# Combine data into one single variable laravel php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have three models: `Country.php`,`Category.php` and `Region.php`. All these models contains a common field named `title` in database.

I want to extract the `title` field from each model and create an array variable, so that I can run it in `foreach` loop in my view.

What would be the optimal method to do so?

Comment: `https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck` will help you extract `title`. Pluck will give you an array. You can merge the resulting arrays to get the array you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went for the `union` query:

```js
        $opt1 = DB::table('countries')
        ->select('countries.name');

        $opt2 = DB::table('tourcategories')
        ->select('tourcategories.name');

        $opt3 = DB::table('regions')
        ->select('regions.name')
        ->union($opt1)
        ->union($opt2)
        ->get();

        dd($opt3);
```

If anyone has another optimal method feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming that you have related this models
$counties = County::with(['category','region'])->get();

// And in view
@foreach($counties as $county)
    {{$county->title}}
    {{$county->category->title}}
    {{$county->region->title}}
@endforeach
```